# community user is not able to see FullPhotoUrl on user object

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I have a VF page where I have Img tag for which the source is coming from User object. Community User when logs in, is not able to see the photo.

Can anyone tell me the way to display user photo on the VF Page for community user?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Community by default the 'fullphotourl' field is not visible to community users.

A simple work around is to create a text field to store the field value from a trigger upon photo update.

Note: If community is enabled to 'view all users', you will be able to access the photo's from Chatter API. Never tested from fullphotourl

Comment: But in this case, the Salesforce FullPhotoUrl and Community Url will be different. But still works?

Like Salesforce url will be : https://na.salesforceurl.com/photoUrl/Id/F
and Community Url will be something like, https://Community.salesforce.com/.....